# Why eventListener re-render React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a stopwatch in React.js and i am wondering why `window.addEventListener('keydown', callback)` re-render my component?

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './App.scss';

import Timer from './Timer';
import Button from './Button';
import Time from './Time';

const App = () => {
  const [isRunning, setIsRunning] = useState(false);
  const [start, setStart] = useState(new Time(0));
  const [stop, setStop] = useState(new Time(0));

  const handleStart = () => {
    const now = new Date();
    setIsRunning(true);
    setStart(new Time(now));
    setStop(new Time(now));
  };

  const handleStop = () => {
    setIsRunning(false);
    setStop(new Time(new Date()));
  };

  const getTime = () => {
    if (isRunning) {
      return new Time(new Date().getTime() - start.origin);
    } else {
      return new Time(stop.origin - start.origin);
    }
  };

  const handleKeyDown = (key) => {
    console.log(key.code === 'Space');
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown);
    };
  });

  return (
    <div className="stopwatch">
      <Timer getTime={getTime} />
      <div className="buttons">
        <Button role={'start'} callback={handleStart} />
        <Button role={'stop'} callback={handleStop} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

When i click start and then stop after let's say 3s. `<Timer />` show correctly time that has passed, but then when i press Space on keyboard `<Timer />` is re-rendering, showing new time. Then, when i switch my web-browser to VSCode and again to web-browser, `<Timer />` isn't re-rendering

---

Here is my `Timer` component

```js
import { memo, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

const Timer = ({ getTime }) => {
  const timer = useRef();

  console.log('timer rendered');

  useEffect(() => {
    function run() {
      const time = getTime().formatted();
      timer.current.textContent = `${time.m}:${time.s}.${time.ms}`;

      requestAnimationFrame(run);
    }

    run();

    return () => {
      cancelAnimationFrame(run);
    };
  });

  return <div ref={timer} className="timer"></div>;
};

export default memo(Timer);
```

no matter if I use `[]` in both or none of `useEffect` nothing changes.

Comment: The useEffect hook is being triggered after 3s (I assume you have a timeout within your Timer component). Have you tried  useEffect(()=>{.... your code},[ ]) ?

Comment: Another issue is with [`cancelAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/cancelAnimationFrame). The function expects a request ID returned by [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame), not the callback passed to it.

Comment: I put together a [code sandbox of your code](https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-noyce-nw88h?file=/src/Time.js) which seems to work. The only way I can duplicate what I think you're saying about the space bar is if the start/stop buttons are the active element when I hit the space bar, in which case it causes the button event to fire.

Comment: @David784 Yes! You are right the problem is that buttons are active element when space bar is hit. Thanks a lot! :) Is there are any solution to avoid that, or i sholud use other key?

Comment: If it's an option, I'd recommend picking a different key. It might be possible to change the default behavior with the space bar, but you'd be fighting against the browser's native functionality which is likely to be more frustrating for you and your users.

Answer (score 0):

As @davood-falahati says, adding an empty array as a second argument to `useEffect` would probably be desirable. From the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect):

> ... If you want to run an effect and clean it up only once (on mount and unmount), you can pass an empty array ([]) as a second argument. This tells React that your effect doesn’t depend on any values from props or state, so it never needs to re-run. This isn’t handled as a special case — it follows directly from how the dependencies array always works. ...

In your use case:

```
useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown);

  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown);
  };
}, []);
```

Comment: Empty array of dependencies doesnt work. Behavior is the same.